# Nodes in Decision Tree in R - more nodes needed

Tags: r, classification, nodes, decision-tree

I created a decision tree in R. When I plotted it I had only 3 nodes (1 root and 2 terminal). The formula that I used to create the decision tree is

```
 >FertilityTree <- rpart(Output~ Age + Surgery + RDrugs + SpermCount +      Smoker, data = FertilityTree, method = "class")
```

The graphic that was produced is:
http://rpubs.com/BonitaWilliams/fertilitydecisiontree

Could you please help me with a graphic that shows more nodes? Or tell me why I have so few nodes?

Comment: I just see a blank page at http://rpubs.com/BonitaWilliams/fertilitydecisiontree; also, can you include your `library`/ `require` statements pls? Is the data part of an existing package?

Comment: Why should there be more nodes? The decision tree fitting has decided that's enough nodes to make the best decision without overfitting, if I understand decision trees properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are parameters that can be supplied to provide further information to the splitting algorithm that may increase (or decrease) the number of nodes. If you have a particular outcome for which an error is expected to be more costly, then you need to assign a different `loss` to it. With no example data there can be no tested example code, but the form of that 'loss' specification would be something like this:

```
FertilityTree <- rpart(Output~ Age + Surgery + RDrugs + SpermCount +
                          Smoker, 
                       data = FertilityTree, method = "class", 
                       parms=list(loss=matrix(c(0,1,2,0),2) )
```

I cannot guarantee that it will be available until the end of SO (or of the universe whichever comes first), but at the moment you can find a [discussion and worked example here.](http://www.louisaslett.com/Courses/Data_Mining_09-10/ST4003-Lab4-New_Tree_Data_Set_and_Loss_Matrices.pdf) The loss matrix needs to have positive off-axis and zero on-axis elements. There are other parameters that may be adjusted as well, including adjustments to 'prior' and changing the splitting criterion to "information". See the `parms` section of `?rpart` for the requirements on these options. There is also the possibility of changing the splitting criterion to a user supplied version. Terry Therneau [posted this in 2011 on Rhelp.](http://markmail.org/download.xqy?id=x2u6uzp3qgqkxx4j&number=1)

It's also possible to use `rpart.control`, a list that is supplied as an argument with that name. You might try `rpart.control=list(minsplit=10)` as a simple first effort at allowing further splits. Changing the complexity parameter, `cp`, may also have some effect. This is the `Usage` section from the help page::

```
?rpart.control
rpart.control(minsplit = 20, minbucket = round(minsplit/3), cp = 0.01, 
              maxcompete = 4, maxsurrogate = 5, usesurrogate = 2, xval = 10,
              surrogatestyle = 0, maxdepth = 30, ...)
```